# Dynamic Binding in C#

Tags: c#, dynamic-binding

```
class A 
 {
   public virtual void WhoAreYou() { Console.WriteLine("I am an A"); }
 }
class B : A
{
  public override void WhoAreYou() { Console.WriteLine("I am a B"); }
}
class C : B
{
 public new virtual void WhoAreYou() { Console.WriteLine("I am a C"); }
}
class D : C 
{
  public override void WhoAreYou() { Console.WriteLine("I am a D"); }
}


C c = new D();
c.WhoAreYou();// "I am a D"
A a = new D();
a.WhoAreYou();// "I am a B" !!!!
```

How the reference is allocated internally,**reference A contains the reference of B?**
Can any one explain Whats going On?

Comment: Um I might be wrong but I think this is what's happening. When you declare an object of class D and assign it to a class C --- class C has a virtual function and in that case it will just use D's overwrite function. But when you declare an object of class D and assign it to a class A what happens is because D inherits from C and C from B and B finally inherits from A but at the same time overwrites A then you have that print statement.

Comment: how about: reading the msdn and trying to understand the virtual/override/new-machine? your example is totally clear!

Comment: @Flo: In first case the object C has the reference of D it calls D's method. But in Second case obviously A has the reference of D, while method invoke how it invoke B's method (what happen internally).. Quiet Confusing..

Comment: Does `new virtual` even make sense conceptually, what is your intended result?

Comment: @Matthew : Obviously hide the base class implementation and let the derived to override.

Comment: @MSDK It would do that without the `new` keyword.

Comment: @Matthew: But Compiler throw warning if i let the method with virtual alone.

Comment: @MSK Not if you have it `override`

Comment: @Matthew: Ya right. But if i put override it will invoke D's method,Obviously the last one in override hierarchy.

Comment: @MSK not if you instanciate a `new C()`.

Comment: @Matthew : Ur right. But my point for this case : A a = new D();
a.WhoAreYou();

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In class `C`, the method `WhoAreYou()` doesn't override the base class method, as it is defined with `new` keyword which adds a *new* method with the *same* name which *hides* the base class method. That is why this:

```
C c = new D();
c.WhoAreYou();// "I am a D"
```

invokes the overridden method in `D` which overrides  its base class method defined with `new` keyword.

However, when the target type is `A`, then this:

```
A a = new D();
a.WhoAreYou();// "I am a B" !!!!
```

invokes the overridden method in `B`, as you're calling the method on `a` of type `A` whose method is overriden by `B`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Nawaz. A has the reference of D, A doesnt know about its child classes. So, I have to track from derived one. Is it so? If not means .. But it will be better if how the reference of D call B's method and how it tracks the derived classes from A (in the aspect of method tables) like internal stuff..

Answer (score 3):

Your class C WhoAreYou() method is 'new', and therefor hiding the one from B. That means that the override in class D is overriding C's method instead of B's (which is overriding A's).

Since you have a reference to an A, the furthest down the hierarchy of it's WhoAreYou() function is the one in class B.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It is mean, that the C's

```
public new virtual void WhoAreYou(){}
```

breaks the chain of virtual methods.

When you call the method WhoAreYou() of D by reference of A. The virtuality starts work, but it breaks at C.